# Android Spinner Text Color dropdown

Tags: android

I cant figure out why my text color for the spinner does not change color. Could you help with figuring this out please.

```
 <style name="Theme.Material_Dark." parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>

 <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_bg_dk</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#424242</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a TextView layout.
dropdown_spinner_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

Then set that as your dropdown resource.

```
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_spinner_text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my code to reflect the overall parent. This did not work for me. I am using a spinner with the android:entries="@array/theme_array".

Comment: Are you saying that you got it working?  If not, can you post your spinner code from your activity?

Comment: I have not got it working yet. When I get back in the office I will post the spinner code.

Answer (score 0):

add the the declared item style to textAppearance

```
 <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_bg_dk</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem"</item>

</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item> //drop down item text color
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#424242</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I lost you? is the textAppearance not already assigned to style SpinnerItem.DropDownItem with the item of android:textColor? Or is this in the wrong place?

Comment: I follow now that I looked a little more closely. I see that in the SpinnerItem the android:textAppearance was added. I will give this a try when I get back to the office.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this did not change the text color of the dropdown text.